# Greek table of Contents created with pdfmod

Tags: pdf, encoding, pdf-bookmarks

I'm using pdfmod to create a ToC for a pdf, with greek characters. Although when I edit it greek characters are shown properly, when I save it neither Okular nor any pdf viewer displays them properly.

Note that other pdf's with greek ToC, are shown properly in Okular.

Any ideas?

Comment: `pdfmod` does not seem to deal with UTF-8 characters in bookmarks properly. I am forced to use another tool to edit the bookmarks.